# laravel - inner join query for three tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to join `department d` table with `department dl` table and `user u` table. I have done this in SQL query.

```
SELECT distinct(dl.head),
       u.user_name,
       u.id
from department d
inner join department dl on d.parent_department_string_id=dl.string_id
inner join users u on dl.head=u.user_name
where d.sl_flag=1
```

I want to do the same in Laravel query. Is it possible to join the same table using join in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
$departmentData = DB::table('department AS d')
            ->innerJoin('department AS d1', function($join) {
                $join->on('d.parent_department_string_id', '=', 'd1.string_id');
            })
            ->innerJoin('users AS u', function($userJoin) {
                $userJoin->on('d1.head', '=', 'u.user_name');
            })
            ->where('d.sl_flag', '=', 1)
            ->select(\DB::raw('distinct(dl.head) AS head'), 'u.user_name', 'u.id')
            ->get();
```